# why css opacity effect not working in chrome?

Tags: css, overlay, transparency, opacity

```
.overlayupload {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  opacity: 0.4; /* also -moz-opacity, etc. */
  -webkit-opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Above is the css that am using to overlay an transperent div while doing some processing and making the screen disable..but this only works in mozila..i want to make it works in chrome too..so can any one please tell me how can i do that?

Following is the div..

```
<div class="overlayupload" id="uploadprogress"
                        style="display: none"></div>
```

Comment: why ur using `display:none` ? i think it should be `display:block` and here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xmbLN/

Comment: the css is perfect you need to apply display-> block/none using javascript/jquery when u need the transparent layer.

Comment: yes..i know..and am doing that..but its showing in mozila only..but thats not working in chrome..am making it visible with the 
  $("#uploadprogress").css("display", "block");

Comment: The issue might be on the JavaScript, don't have any JS error? Also have you tried to in inspect the element and manually add your CSS style using Chrome developer tools?

Comment: look at this fiddle its working in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/xmbLN/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
#uploadprogress{
      opacity:0.8!important;
}
```

why are you using `display:none;` it hides whole div